# Select ArcMap attributes that are in CSV

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table, csv, select-by-attribute

Is there an ArcMap 10.1 method for selecting only attribute rows that have an identifier in common with those in a CSV sheet?

I exported an attribute table (5000 rows) and eliminated all but the specific 257 rows I am interested in (based on an APN number). The resulting CSV has the same number of columns with the same headings, just fewer number of rows. Now I am having trouble figuring out how to map only the rows from the attribute table that I am interested in.

Doing a join just appends the tables, but doesn't get me to my goal of eliminating the attribute rows that aren't in my CSV sheet.

Comment: Just select the rows in the joined table where `csv.APN_number IS NULL` (in the second APN Number field from the CSV, not the original APN Number field).

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the attribute table and click the join choice.  The Join Data window has a choice that says keep all records or Keep only matching records to create the target table.

[image]